# How to remove space created by sticky element

Tags: html, css

My chatbox (circled in red) is creating all this unnecessary space at the top (highlighted in yellow) even though it has position sticky and will never be in this area. However as you can see all the other elements are affected by this. How do I stop this from happening?[image: My webpage]

```css
.sticky{
 position:sticky;
 top:50%;
 left:80%;
 background:grey;
 width:50%;
}
```

```html
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element with space below me :(</p>
<div class="sticky">
  <p>Im an element in a sticky div and I caused that space!</p>
  <p>Im an element in a sticky div and I caused that space!</p>
  <p>Im an element in a sticky div and I caused that space!</p>
  <p>Im an element in a sticky div and I caused that space!</p>
  <p>Im an element in a sticky div and I caused that space!</p>
</div>
<p>Im an element with space above me :(</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
```

Comment: Please show relevant code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I created an example that demonstrates the same issue and attached it to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone that might come across this in years to come, position:fixed; exists its basically sticky but absolute

```css
.fixed{
 position:fixed;
 top:10%;
 left:50%;
 background:grey;
 width:50%;
}
```

```html
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element with NO space below me :D</p>
<div class="fixed">
  <p>Im an element in a FIXED div and I DIDNT cause a space!</p>
  <p>Im an element in a FIXED div and I DIDNT cause a space!</p>
  <p>Im an element in a FIXED div and I DIDNT cause a space!</p>
  <p>Im an element in a FIXED div and I DIDNT cause a space!</p>
  <p>Im an element in a FIXED div and I DIDNT cause a space!</p>
</div>
<p>Im an element with NO space above me :D</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect but I include it in case it helps lead to a more perfect solution.

In this snippet the sticky div has height 0 with an inner div which takes the gray background.

Some space is taken up, but not the full amount of all the child p elements.

```css
.sticky{
 position:sticky;
 top:50%;
 left:80%;
 background:grey;
 width:50%;
 height: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.inner {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element with space below me :(</p>
<div class="sticky">
<div class="inner">
  <p>Im an element in a sticky div and I caused that space!</p>
  <p>Im an element in a sticky div and I caused that space!</p>
  <p>Im an element in a sticky div and I caused that space!</p>
  <p>Im an element in a sticky div and I caused that space!</p>
  <p>Im an element in a sticky div and I caused that space!</p>
</div>
</div>
<p>Im an element with space above me :(</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
<p>Im an element!</p>
```